# How render HTML table in NativeScript web view or html view?

Tags: android, gridview, html-table, nativescript

In my project I have to render an array of objects as a table, but I don't want to use `GridView` because this component is very hard to customize.

How can I render an HTML Table in `HtmlView` or `WebView`?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your desired HTML and assign it later to HtmlView or WebView like this:

```
<HtmlView html="your html" />
...
<WebView src="your html" />
```

Or using code:

```
var htmlViewModule = require("ui/html-view")
var htmlView = new htmlViewModule.HtmlView();
htmlView.html = "your html";
...
var webViewModule = require("ui/web-view")
var webView = new webViewModule.WebView();
webView.src= "your html";
```

If you need to arrange however UI elements in NativeScript you need to use `GridLayout`. You can simply add desired UI elements using `addChild()` method and assign desired row/column using `setColumn()` and `setRow()` static methods. For example:

```
var gridModule = require("ui/layouts/grid-layout");
var buttonModule = require("ui/button");

var grid = new gridModule.GridLayout();
grid.addColumn(new gridModule.ItemSpec(80, gridModule.GridUnitType.pixel));
grid.addColumn(new gridModule.ItemSpec(1, gridModule.GridUnitType.star));
grid.addRow(new gridModule.ItemSpec(1, gridModule.GridUnitType.auto));
grid.addRow(new gridModule.ItemSpec(1, gridModule.GridUnitType.auto));

var button new buttonModule.Button();
grid.addChild(button);
gridModule.GridLayout.setRow(button, 1);
gridModule.GridLayout.setColumn(button, 1);
...
```